# Azure Certificate based authentication is not working in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, x509certificate

i'm trying to configure CBA in Azure AD. but i'm failing to access with my self signed cert.
i configured everything as per the MS docs and i'm afraid that i'm missing something with the certificate.

i created self signed cert from azure key vault and uploaded the root to Azure AD and kept my private key in my PC, i get the popup but not able to access.

should i have a different certificate?
also i didnt configured CRL path, it's a test env i just want to check the authentication.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I generated the **Self Signed-In certificate** and exported it:

[image]

For **sample**, I enabled MFA for one user and added the user as the Member for **`testrukgrp`**:

[image]

I uploaded the **certificate in the Certificate authorities** like below:

[image]

Enabled the CBA:

[image]

And edited the **configuration** like below:

[image]

In the **Registration Campaign enable the state**:

[image]

I tried to login with the user and got the **certificate popup**:

[image]

Now, I selected the certificate from the popup:

[image]

And **I am successfully able to login with the certificate** like below:

[image]

**To resolve the issue, check the below:**

- Make sure that the certificate is valid, if not trying to create the certificate by using the PowerShell script mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/how-to-certificate-based-authentication#add)
- Check whether the certificate is expired.
- If still the issue persists, then it might be due to Certificate Revocation List (CRL).

To know more in detail, **refer** the below links:

[Azure AD certificate-based authentication technical deep dive - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-certificate-based-authentication-technical-deep-dive)

[Configuring Certificate-Based Authentication (CBA) with Azure AD | by Jonas Markström](https://swjm.blog/configuring-certificate-based-authentication-cba-with-azure-ad-88af559cf17d)

Comment: Thanks, can you please elaborate on how did you manage to issue a certificate?

Comment: I followed the script given in the MsDoc stated above

Comment: Thanks, but can you please elaborate on this 1st line ps code $cert=Get-Content -Encoding byte "[LOCATION OF THE CEr File? Should i issue another cert before that?